# Using PHP DateInterval to create recurring events

Tags: php, datetime, date

So I have spent quite a bit of time researching how best to add recurring events to my calendar application.

I would like to use the PHP DateInterval function and have formulated the code below to try and work out how to create a recurring event based on the original events `Start Date`, `Finish Date` and the `EndDate of Recurrence`.

```
//user defined event start and finish dates
$eventStart = new DateTime( '2011-01-31 09:00:00' );
$eventFinish = new DateTime( '2011-01-32 17:00:00' );

//user defined event recurring end date
$endRecurring = new DateTime( '2011-05-31 23:59:59' );

//define for recurring period function
$begin = $eventStart;
$end = $endRecurring;

//define our interval
$interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString('next friday');
$period = new DatePeriod($begin, $interval, $end, DatePeriod::EXCLUDE_START_DATE);

//loop through and create new dates for recurring events
foreach ( $period as $dt )
  $recurringStartDate = $dt->format( "l Y-m-d H:i:s\n" );
  $recurringEndDate = ?NOT SURE HOW TO PROCESS THE END DATE IN THIS START DATE FOREACH LOOP?
```

This should hopefully create a list of new event start dates. **BUT I also need to define new end dates for my recurring events**. How do I do this? Do I need to process this in the event start date foreach loop?

My other question is how I could combine multiple dateIntervals to take care of `Repeat every Monday, Wednesday and Friday`? Currently only single dateIntervals are working like `next friday`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is a Date/Calendar recursion library for PHP 5.2+ by Thomas Planer. Its not DateInterval, but it seems to do the trick. Check it out at https://github.com/tplaner/When.

Comment: When is awesome, and I'm now using it!

Answer (score 9):

Hi I had to develop something similar and i did the flowing:

```
$event_date = "2012-10-06";
$event_end_date = "2012-10-08";
$event_repetition_type = "Daily";

$date_calculation = "";
switch ($event_repetition_type) {
    case "Daily":
    $date_calculation = " +1 day";
    break;
case "Weekly":
    $date_calculation = " +1 week";
    break;
case "Monthly":
    $date_calculation = " +1 month";
    break;
default:
    $date_calculation = "none";
}

$dateArray[] =  $event_date;

$day = strtotime($event_date);
$to = strtotime($event_end_date);

while( $day <= $to ) 
{
    $day = strtotime(date("Y-m-d", $day) . $date_calculation);
    $dateArray[] = date("Y-m-d" , $day);
    }


//here make above array as key in $a array
$a = array_fill_keys($dateArray, 'none');
print_r($a);
```

Comment: Nice ... Did u ever make any improvments to this code ? Check against holidays ? Pls do share if possible ?

Comment: Hi @MarcoZen we check hollidays in a manual table as any api or other functions that we try fail with some specific days.

Comment: Noted. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 0):

i use strtotime() for this sort of thing. seems to be easier. works like this.

```
$new_timestamp = strtotime('+1 week', time()); // + 1 week from today
$new_timestamp = strtotime('+1 week', $new_timestamp); // + 2 weeks from now
$new_timestamp = strtotime('+1 month', $new_timestamp); // + 1 month and 2 weeks from now
```

you can even start with whatever date string you want like this

```
$new_timestamp = strtotime('+1 week', strtotime('2011-01-31 09:00:00')); // one week from 2011-01-31
```

then you can output the timestamp in any format using the date() function

```
echo date('Y-m-d', $new_timestamp);
```

Let me know if you have questions.

Comment: Hello, Thanks for your answer. I have looked into using strtotime() but it leaves me in the same position with the problem in the foreach loop. My application requires me to generate a batch of recurring events which I can do for the start date of each recurring event but not the end date. Also, how can I batch multiple days together to solve the `Repeat every Monday, Wednesday and Friday` issue with strtotime()?

Comment: strtotime('next friday + 1 week')? figure out the amount of time between the start and end, and add it to your new start date.

Comment: repeat on certain weekdays, youd have to keep them stored somewhere, and use whatever the next one is. you could process a weeks worth of dates, sort, then put the one at the top (earliest next X date).

Comment: maybe converting dates to julian dates will help.  i believe there is some relation like being evenly divisible by 7 means that is a sunday.  if you want all mondays between two dates, just get the julian dates which have mod 7 give 1 and convert them back to gregorian date format.

Answer (score 0):

You could calculate a DateInterval for the duration of the user defined events like so:

```
$eventStart = new DateTime( '2011-01-31 09:00:00' );
$eventFinish = new DateTime( '2011-01-31 17:00:00' );
$eventDuration = $eventStart->diff($eventFinish);
```

then in your loop, just clone the recurring date and add the calculated `$eventDuration` back on

```
$until = clone $dt;
$until->add($eventDuration);
```

Also you should do some error handling as your user end data is "2011-01-32"!

Answer (score 0):

This post is old but it should be noted that when talking about recurrence the way is the [iCalendar (RFC 5545, RFC 2445) standard](https://icalendar.org/resources.html)

there are several PHP libraries that address this issue: [see in github](https://github.com/search?q=php%20rrules)